# Can some help me to implement calendar widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar, flutter-layout, android-calendar

Click the date range display to select a date range. Your date range stays active as you switch from one report to another. All reports compare metric values for the date range you choose to metric values from the previous period.

• Select Today, Yesterday, This week, *Last
7 days*, Last 30 days, Quarter to date, or
Custom.
• Select Custom to create a date range beginning and ending on the dates you select.
User can select frequently use dates and make a tab manually.
When you compare date ranges, Analytics uses the same day of the week to start
each date range. For example, if you use the date range Last week Sun - Sat, then
the comparison is the previous week of Sunday to Saturday. If you use a custom
date range, for example, 7 days beginning on a Monday, then the comparison begins
with the previous Monday.
The selected date will be automatically selected at the time of login of each
individual user.

[image: 1]

Comment: For my understanding, why do you need them highlighted in the first place. May be I can suggest some other way of achieving your goal

Comment: because its date range

Comment: and what's the purpose of that date range?

Comment: for fetch reports from server etc

Comment: You can simply prompt user to select a date and whether he wants to see a data of previous 5 days or coming 5 days, and label the results accordingly.

Comment: Found a pub package that might help you https://pub.dev/packages/date_range_picker

Comment: thank you for sharing link i have seen this link but how to add chips or tag of "Today", "Yesterday" in below dialog

Comment: No idea about that.